# How to pivot_wider/melt a matrix of values with multiple header rows in Excel sheet?

Tags: r, excel, pivot

I've got a number of Excel sheets, each with a matrix of about 120 lab results and 150 patients. However, the lab results are stored as rows starting at row 4, and the patients are stored with extra header column data in rows 1 to 3. So the Excel sheet look like this:

[image: Excel sheet input]

And I want to read it and convert it to a longer/normalised dataframe, basically like this mockup:
[image: Desired dataframe format in Rstudio]

I think it could be processed with `pivot_longer` or `melt`, but the empty cells in the top left are causing trouble, i.e. the column headers of the lab result start at row 4, and the patient colums start at column C.

Btw the patient column names always start at position of column D, but obviously the actual names `EXA_2665`, `EXA_2707` etc are not known beforehand, they will be newly issued patient IDs.

Here is the code I've got so far.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

##xls_data <- read_excel(path = "lab2_exafinal.xlsx", sheet = "Labata")
## TEST hardcoded data for testing purposes
xls_data2 <- read.table(text = "
...1,...2,Patient-Id,EXA_2665,EXA_2707,EXA_2971
,,Tube,87019054,87065976,87093024
,,Tube-Pos,C12,D01,D02
LabId,LabDescr,WeightFact,,,
9,HbA1c,1.00,1.784,0.419,1.045
37,HDL-Chol,1.00,0.684,2.172,1.954
38,LDL-Chol,1.00,2.438,1.995,0.806
41,Glucose,1.00,1.366,1.47,0.978
", header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = "")  

library(reshape)
df_melt <- melt(xls_data, id.vars=c("...1", "...2"))
# error: names do not match previous names

pivoted_data <- pivot_longer(
  xls_data,
  cols = names(xls_data[3,]),
  names_to = "patient",
  values_to = "value" 
  )
#no error but not quite the desired result
```

**EDIT**: @Jon-Spring suggested using `dput` to share the exact formatting/structure of data as resulted by the `read_excel` function reading the Excel file (btw it also read `1.045` as `1.044999` etc but for now that's a separate issue) btw also notice that the patient labelnames may include the `-` character.

```
#xls_data <- read_excel(path = "lab2_exafinal.xlsx", sheet = "Labata")
#dput(xls_data)
xls_data <- structure(
  list(
    ...1 = c(NA, NA, "LabId", "9", "37", "38", "41"),
    ...2 = c(NA, NA, "LabDescr", "HbA1c", "HDL-Chol", "LDL-Chol", "Glucose"),
    ...3 = c("Tube", "Tube-Pos", "WeightFact", "1,00", "1,00", "1,00", "1,00"),
    EXA_2665 = c("87019054", "C12", NA, "1.784", "0.68400000000000005", "2.4380000000000002", "1.3660000000000001"),
    EXA_2707 = c("87065976", "D01", NA, "0.41899999999999998", "2.1720000000000002", "1.9950000000000001", "1.47"),
    EXA_2971 = c("87093024", "D02", NA, "1.0449999999999999", "1.954", "0.80600000000000005", "0.97799999999999998")
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -7L)
  )
```

When I read the Excel sheet using `readxl::read_excel` the first columns will be `...1`, `...2`. So when using `melt` I *think* those should be the `id.vars` parameters(?) but it gives an error message. The result of `pivot_longer` looks closer to what I'm trying to do, but the problem is there are extra header rows andd I don't know how to use (or just remove?) those.

I can think of other ways to do it, but I don't know *how* to do that in Rstudio:

- Somehow try to read is as two separate data frames, the patients (C1..F3) and the lab values (A4..F8) and then merge it.
- Or first copy the patient header names `EXA_2665` etc to the empty row 4, and then re-interpret just the A4..F8 region

Any other idea how to best approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unheadr` package offers some tools for reshaping tables with these sorts of features that might make them more compact for human readers but trickier to parse with code.

Here, along the lines of your 2nd idea, we can combine the four rows of headers (the first of which comes in as a header, the next three as data rows). I specified `-` as the separator because `_` already appears as a non-separator in `PatientId`.

Then we can `pivot_longer` those combined headers into multiple `names` columns alongside each value.

```
library(unheadr)
xls_data2 |>
  # take the first three rows and combine them with the header
  mash_colnames(n_name_rows = 3, sep = "-") |>
  # reshape everything besides the first three columns, separating the 
  # combined headers into new columns named
  # 1) the third original header
  # 2-4) the first three data rows in the third column
  pivot_longer(-c(1:3), names_sep = "-", 
               names_to = c(colnames(xls_data2)[3], xls_data2[1:3, 3])) |>
  dplyr::rename(LabId = 1, LabDescr = 2, WeightFact2 = 3) 
  # dplyr::rename to avoid conflict with `reshape::rename`
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 12 × 8
   LabId LabDescr WeightFact2 PatientId Tube     TubePos WeightFact value
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <chr>
 1 9     HbA1c    1.00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         1.784
 2 9     HbA1c    1.00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         0.419
 3 9     HbA1c    1.00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         1.045
 4 37    HDL-Chol 1.00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         0.684
 5 37    HDL-Chol 1.00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         2.172
 6 37    HDL-Chol 1.00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         1.954
 7 38    LDL-Chol 1.00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         2.438
 8 38    LDL-Chol 1.00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         1.995
 9 38    LDL-Chol 1.00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         0.806
10 41    Glucose  1.00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         1.366
11 41    Glucose  1.00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         1.47 
12 41    Glucose  1.00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         0.978
```

---

Edit with `dput(xls_data)` example:

```
xls_data |>
  mash_colnames(n_name_rows = 3, sep = "@") |>
  pivot_longer(-c(1:3), names_sep = "@", 
               names_to = c(colnames(xls_data2)[3], xls_data2[1:3, 3])) |>
  dplyr::rename(LabId = 1, LabDescr = 2, WeightFact2 = 3) |>
  dplyr::mutate(across(value, as.numeric))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 12 × 8
   LabId LabDescr WeightFact2 PatientId Tube     TubePos WeightFact value
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>     <chr>    <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 9     HbA1c    1,00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         1.78 
 2 9     HbA1c    1,00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         0.419
 3 9     HbA1c    1,00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         1.04 
 4 37    HDL-Chol 1,00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         0.684
 5 37    HDL-Chol 1,00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         2.17 
 6 37    HDL-Chol 1,00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         1.95 
 7 38    LDL-Chol 1,00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         2.44 
 8 38    LDL-Chol 1,00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         2.00 
 9 38    LDL-Chol 1,00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         0.806
10 41    Glucose  1,00        EXA_2665  87019054 C12     NA         1.37 
11 41    Glucose  1,00        EXA_2707  87065976 D01     NA         1.47 
12 41    Glucose  1,00        EXA_2971  87093024 D02     NA         0.978
```

Comment: Thank this results in the normalised dataset, except for one thing. When you load the actual Excel file with `read_excel()` then the datatypes are slightly different(?) and I needed to add an `unlist(` in the "names_to" line so like this `names_to = c(colnames(xls_data2)[3], unlist(xls_data2[1:3, 3]))) |>` but othen than that it work, thanks.

Comment: I tried to keep the example in the original question simple, but the actual files have 6 header lines instead of 3, and there are 4 fixed columns (`LabId,LabDescr,WeightFact,LabTrack`) instead of just 3. I'm adapting your example code for this and trying to understand what each line does, but can you explain what the `n_name_rows = 3` and `-c(1:3)` and `xls_data2[1:3, 3]` means?

Comment: Edited above with new comments. `n_name_rows = 3` specifies that the first three rows of data should be combined in with the existing column headers. `-c(1:3)` is a shorthand for "all the columns except the first three. We could alternately say `4:6` to reshape the 4th thru 6th column, or write out the new longer headers. `xls_data2[1:3, 3]` means "rows 1:3 and column 3 of `xls_data2`.

Comment: FYI if you want to share the formatting/structure of data, not just its printed appearance, you can use the helpful `dput()` function to convert an R object into code that generates that object. So after your `read_excel` step you could use `dput(YOUR_TABLE[1:7, 1:6])` to output code that generates the first 7 rows and 6 columns of that table.

Comment: On second thought my earlier comment was incorrect, I can't seem to get the example code working for an actual Excel file. It seems like the dataframe is slighty different class type when I use `read_excel()`. The column objects contains an additional `[1:7]` so for example `$ EXA_2665 : chr [1:7] "87019054" "C12" etc` instead of just `$ EXA_2665 : chr "87019054" "C12" etc` and when I run the example code the result contains columns `Tube`=`E`, `TubePos`=`X`, `WeightFact`=`A` (?).

Comment: Please see my comment just prior. We will be in a much better position to help if you can provide specific reproducible example data.

Comment: I've added the exact data structure when reading the Excel file using `dput`, see the EDIT in the original question

Comment: I just realised, some of the patient labels in the actual Excel files also contain `-` characters. So I tried your code but instead of `sep = "-" / names_sep = "-"` I was using `"|"` in both places thinking it wouldn't matter which separator character you use. However, somehow that seems to go wrong somewhere. When I use `"="` in both places then it does seem to work correctly(?)

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation, the issue with the `|` separator seems like a bug(?) in `pivot_longer` I've submitted it as an issue here -> https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1503 other than that this was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like it there is a powerquery method as below. Its dynamic and would accommodate any number of PatientID data columns

Bring the data in without any headers

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Keep Rows" = Table.FirstN(Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Column1", "Column2"}),3),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Transpose(#"Keep Rows"), [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Custom", each {1 .. Table.RowCount(Source)-4}),
Part1 = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
#"Promoted Headers2" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Skip(Source,3), [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
leading=3, groupsof=1,
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers2", "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading), each Text.From(_)),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),leading+groupsof)),
Part2 = Table.RenameColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1", "LabID"}, {"Column2", "LabDescr"}, {"Column3", "WeightFact"}, {"Column4", "Value"}}),
Combine=Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Part2) & Table.ToColumns(Part1),Table.ColumnNames(Part2)&Table.ColumnNames(Part1)),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(Combine,{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns2"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but due to other requirements I really do need to process these files in R studio, even though the source data files are Excel workbooks.

Comment: no worries. Happy to attempt a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "pure" `tidyverse` approach you can use the following:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

xls_data <- structure(
   list(
      ...1 = c(NA, NA, "LabId", "9", "37", "38", "41"),
      ...2 = c(NA, NA, "LabDescr", "HbA1c", "HDL-Chol", "LDL-Chol", "Glucose"),
      ...3 = c("Tube", "TubePos", "WeightFact", "1,00", "1,00", "1,00", "1,00"),
      EXA_2665 = c("87019054", "C12", NA, "1.784", "0.68400000000000005", "2.4380000000000002", "1.3660000000000001"),
      EXA_2707 = c("87065976", "D01", NA, "0.41899999999999998", "2.1720000000000002", "1.9950000000000001", "1.47"),
      EXA_2971 = c("87093024", "D02", NA, "1.0449999999999999", "1.954", "0.80600000000000005", "0.97799999999999998")
   ),
   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
   row.names = c(NA, -7L)
)

# 1. Get start of the data
data_start <- xls_data %>%
   select(first_col = 1) %>%
   summarize(start = which(!is.na(first_col))[1L] + 1L) %>% 
   pull(start)

# 2. Extract the 2 data blocks

values <- xls_data %>% 
   slice(data_start:n()) %>% 
   set_names(
      c(
         xls_data %>% 
            slice(data_start - 1L) %>% 
            select(1:3) %>% 
            unlist(),
         names(.)[-(1:3)]
      )
   ) %>% 
   mutate(across(-(2:3), as.numeric)) 

meta <-  xls_data %>% 
   slice(1:(data_start - 2L)) %>% 
   select(-(1:2)) %>% 
   set_names(c("PatientId", names(.)[-1L])) %>% 
   bind_rows(names(.) %>% 
                as.list() %>% 
                set_names(.) %>% 
                as.data.frame(),
             .
   ) %>% 
   t() %>% 
   `colnames<-`(.[1L, ]) %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
   slice(-1L)   

# 3. Reshape and join
values %>% 
   pivot_longer(-(1:3)) %>% 
   inner_join(meta,
              c(name = "PatientId")) %>% 
   rename(PatientId = name) %>% 
   select(LabId:PatientId, Tube:TubePos, Value = value) %>% 
   arrange(PatientId, LabId)
```

Admittedly, much longer code than the excellent proposal of John, but a good (and verbose) exercise to master the `tidyverse` ;)